# Why does comparison statement of three variables in JavaScript return false?

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = {
  name: 'home',
  href: '/'
};
var pathname = "/";
console.log(data.href == pathname == "/")
```

The console.log statement printed "false".

However, if I have the following:

```
var data = {name: 'home', href: '/'};
var pathname = "/";
console.log(data.href == "/");
console.log(data.href == pathname);
console.log(pathname == "/");
```

All three of the console.log statement will print true.

Comment: Left-to-right evaluation... consider `true === "/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator `==` is evaluated left to right. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table)</sup>

```
data.href == pathname == "/"
```

becomes

```
true == "/"
```

which is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(data.href == pathname == "/")
```

All three elements may be the same, but that's not what is being compared here.

Take the second and third elements. Both are `/`, so the result of the comparison is `true`. This is compared with the first element, but `/` is not `true` so the comparison fails.

The exact order of evaluation doesn't matter here. The first comparison returns a boolean, so the second comparison returns `false`.